# Compiling my C++ exe for Linux with VS2019

Tags: c++, linux, cross-platform, visual-studio-2019

I have created a C++ standalone exe with VS2019.
This exe uses 1 external ressource file. 
This exe creates WAV files.

It does not use any special libraries.

I have been asked if this application runs under Linux, too.

What would I have to do / check to see if / how I can compile my application for Linux, and would that be possible using VS2019?

Thank you very much for the help.

ps: Here is a screenshot of the properties of my project:
[image: ros]

Comment: Visual Studio's compiler does *not* build Linux executables. You need to use a different compiler (like GCC or clang) - preferably *on* a Linux system.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But can you have a look at Christoph Miller's answer? Is your comment still valid? If yes, can you please explain?

Comment: I don't have anything to add to that answer. Except maybe that applications compiled for WSL may not run on every Linux distribution out there..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually to build C++ applications for Linux, you must first use a compiler that will build for the target OS. In this case VS2019 (and it's associated compiler) builds executables for Windows only.

If you're trying to target Linux, you have two options:

1. You can move over to a Linux system and build your project with the GNU c++ compiler (I recommend using CMAKE to build your project since it's not tied to any particular IDE and can generate makefiles for gcc). https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/
2. You can install the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and do a remote build with VS2019. You'll see more and more of this these days in production environments. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio-2019-wsl-asan-for-linux-separation-of-build-and-debug/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Even though it's outside of the scope of this question: I'm using wstring all over my code. Can you tell me I have to change that? And if yes, what would you suggest? Thank you!

Comment: @tmighty Since std::wstring is part of the STL, any STL compilant compiler should be able to handle it (In this case you're fine using gcc on Linux and VS2019)! Personally, I'd target any gcc version 8 or higher to get access to C++17. Good luck! :D

Comment: And yes, I have WSL installed, so I will use option 2.

Comment: @tmighty - `wchar_t` is different sizes on Windows (2 bytes) and Linux (4 bytes). When I am writing multi-platform code I use UTF-8 internally. I convert both Windows and Linux to UTF-8. It is especially important with things like hashing passwords.

Comment: @jww Can you explain how that looks?

Comment: @jww Do you mean that you set "Multibyte charset" in the project settings? I'm not sure if that's the correct English term. I guess you know what I mean.

Comment: Or this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/utf-8-set-source-and-executable-character-sets-to-utf-8?view=vs-2019